# UITextView: Background Color while keeping Left/Right Paragraph Indent

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

In my UITextView, I want certain `NSRanges` to be indented left and right equally and be highlighted in a specific color. I am achieving this by modifying `NSMutableAttributedStrings` and setting the `textView.attributedText`. To get the left/right indentation, I'm using `NSMutableParagraphStyle` - however, this is removing the highlighting (`NSBackgroundColor`). How can I get it such that the highlighting starts from the beginning, even with the `headIndent`.

[image: headIndent removes nsbackgroundcolor]

```
 // padding
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.headIndent = 5.0;
    paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 5.0;
    paragraphStyle.tailIndent = -5.0;

     NSDictionary *referenceAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor], NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor brownColor], NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size: 14], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle};
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to give padding in UITextView

```
self.textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
```

Comment: Hi Ashish - this wouldn't fulfill the requirement I listed on the first line however, given this would apply the padding to all NSRanges in my TextView and not just the ones I'm interested in showcasing